# What's the most efficient way to compare a database table with its mirror

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, compare

I have an SQLite database table and an identical mirror table.
The table has an id column (the primary key) and many many other columns. It may contain around 1K rows at a given point.

My program is triggered quite often to check the table against its mirror to see if any change has occurred in any of its columns. I just need to know that a change has happened, I don't care which column content has changed.

I need this check to be very efficient since it happens quite a lot.
I thought about summing the ids and comparing but that's remotely good enough.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into hashing .. that will still require a full read of all the data, though. Other alternatives including a "changestamp" column (which is a hash of the current row). It would need to be updated each write, but could provide a quick way to tell differences (same global ID, different changestamp) and could itself be used as part of the table-hash.

Comment: I thought about using hash but I really want to avoid reading all the data. I'd rather find a way to scan only part of the table or an index so that it will identify a change almost for sure.
I can "live" with a probability of a mistake once in every 1000 scans.

Comment: So then do that. Using a hash (per row or per cols/rows) just gives a nice simple value to use as a check (although you could check each col individually). You can select the rows/columns to hash.